# System.exit() status code not working when compiled into native app

Tags: java, javafx-2, javapackager

I've created a JavaFX 2 app of which I'm adding a command-line mode (so that it can be run in a batch mode from nightly scripts).  For this to be effective, I want to set the exit status to indicate errors.  I'm doing this with this code:

```
if (errorOccurred) {
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

This works fine when I run it from the IntelliJ, and I see this in the Console window:

> Process finished with exit code 255

When I run the jar from the command line it also works:

```
$ java <snip-lots-of-arguments> cool_app.Main
$ echo $?
255
```

But after I use `javapackager` to turn the jar into a native application, it stops working:

```
$ javapackager -deploy -native -outdir out -outfile "cool_app.app" -srcfiles cool_app.jar -appclass cool_app.Main -name "cool_app" -title "cool_app"
$ open out/cool_app.app
$ echo $?
0
```

I'm using JDK 8u40 on MacOS 10.10.4.

Is there something I'm missing?  Or a bug in `javapackager`?